# How to perform action after a file is deleted?

Tags: hooks, files

Is there an API hook I could use to run some custom PHP code after a file is deleted? I need access to the name of the file which has just been deleted.

I attempted using hook_nodeapi, and testing for when the operation is delete, but it seems by this stage the file row has been removed from the database, and I'm left with just information about the node itself.

I'm using Drupal 6. (I see that Drupal 7 *does* have a hook: hook_file_delete)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can use [FileField](http://drupal.org/project/filefield); this module is now part of Drupal 7 core, and provides additions to the API, such as [hook_file_delete()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_file_delete/7).

Comment: Cheers, I'm already using that module, wasn't aware of the extra hook